# Microsoft Identity Platform in an ASP.NET Core project

Tags: c#, microsoft-identity-platform

I have an ASP.NET Core web app project which using Microsoft Identity Platform as the authentication method. I would like to add the REST API feature into the same project but it seems I cannot add the `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi` method together with `AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp`.

In `StartUp.cs` I put both `AddAuthentication` calls together:

```
Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
        .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
            .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(Configuration.GetSection("AzureAd"));
```

There is no error on compilation but when I start the project it immediately returns a 401 error. I think it is because the second `AddAuthentication` line was replace the first one so I cannot start the web site.

I just want to ask is it possible if the project provide both web app and rest API using Microsoft Identity Platform or I need to separate it into two project, one for web app and one for web API. If so how can I share the same DB and models for two project?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: Call `.AddAuthentication()` once, use an extension (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.identity.web.microsoftidentitywebapiauthenticationbuilderextensions.addmicrosoftidentitywebapi?view=azure-dotnet) that takes a scheme parameter. Then you'll probably need 2 authorisation policies, matching against the two auth schemes. (see also https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/authorization/limitingidentitybyscheme?view=aspnetcore-6.0)

Answer (score 2):

I needed to protect both a web API and the Swagger UI. I did it like this:

```cs
builder.Services.AddAuthentication(OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApp(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(JwtBearerDefaults.AuthenticationScheme)
    .AddMicrosoftIdentityWebApi(builder.Configuration);

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen();
```

and then:

```cs
app.UseAuthentication();

app.UseAuthorization();

app.UseSwagger();

app.UseSwaggerUI(c =>
{
    c.SwaggerEndpoint("/swagger/v1/swagger.json", "API v1");
});

app.Map("/swagger/index.html", () => "This endpoint requires authorization")
    .RequireAuthorization(new AuthorizeAttribute
    {
        AuthenticationSchemes = OpenIdConnectDefaults.AuthenticationScheme,
    });

app.MapControllers();
```

This results in web API requiring a bearer token, and the Swagger UI itself redirecting an unauthenticated user to the Azure AD login page (and then logs in).

Comment: wow, I've been days trying to figure this out, I knew it would be a really simple solution..! Thank you so much!!!!